# How to load specific fonts in a LaTeX document

Tags: fonts

Using acrobat reader, I found the following fonts

BmfxsgWrjrkvJhytgsMTMI (Embedded Subset)

Type: Type 1

Encoding: Custom

BmrqlnNncclsHbvffqSpringnew-Regular (Embedded Subset)

Type: Type 1

Encoding: Custom

BqvxwbWrpmvtQtnbsgMTSN (Embedded Subset)

Type: Type 1

Encoding: Custom

BrtcvyWxxjbfKtppbtMSBM10 (Embedded Subset)

Type: Type 1

Encoding: Ansi

CmnypcRnpxkyFfnhmhTimes-Roman (Embedded subset)

Type: Type 1

Encoding: Custom

fmscbcLgglngFxjcrfTimes-Bold (Embedded Subset)

Type: Type 1

Encoding: Roman

HbvwthSjlmgdBwlmdtMyriadPro-Cond (Embedded Subset)

Type: Type 1

Encoding: Custom

JmdssfYtvpsFbyvhwMTWXB (Embedded Subset)

Type: Type 1

Encoding: Custom

JxktwqMchphvQkkfkcTimes-BoldItalic (Embedded Subset)

Type: Type 1

Encoding: Roman

JxxvphMcgpnwNlsvymTimes-Roman (Embedded Subset)

Type: Type 1

Encoding: Roman

KhvgsmWjcsnbRlglkwMTSYB (Embedded Subset)

Type: Type 1

Encoding: Custom

KqppkpKytmmrFkfqvvMyriadPro-SemiCond (embedded Subset)

Type: Type 1

Encoding: Ansi

NxnlsdfcywhyNxxdfkMTMB (Embedded Subset)

Type: Type 1

Encoding: Custom

QpnwmkMsxbdqMxmtdkMTMI (Embedded Subset)

Type: Type 1

Encoding: Custom

QptjjkGccfprPmnbwqMyriadPro-CondIt (Embedded Subset)

Type: Type 1

Encoding: Ansi

RypgtwRgdbdxVmjsknTimes-Italic (Embedded Subset)

Type: Type 1

Encoding: Roman

TprvrjJtgfdcMdrsfnMTEX (Embedded SubSet)

Type: Type 1

Encoding: Custom

TtdlhxJdtxhcLltbcpMTEX (Embedded Subset)

Type: Type 1

Encoding: Custom

XwvvvdYwfhmkGjtdxbMTSYN (Embedded Subset)

Type: Type 1

Encoding: Custom

YxdhgfNynjltFgwjqwrsfs10 (Embedded Subset)

Type: Type 1

Encoding: Ansi

Now, how to load them in a LaTeX document ?

Comment: ignore the random letter prefixes, which are unique to that document, you are looking at Times Roman a Springer font and Mathtime, the latter two are mostly commercial or only available to the publisher. You can get a similar times roman based layout with `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`

Comment: Plus `mathrsfs` for `\mathscr`.

Comment: Thank you @David Carlisle

Comment: @Davislor you mean `\usepackage{mathrsfs}`?

Comment: You can do it that way, but I'd recommend loading alphabets like that with `mathalpha`.